# Counts from 1 to 1500 in 3 seconds jQuery isInViewport

Tags: jquery, viewport

I've made this script that counts from 1 to 1500 in 3 seconds. This works well. But this div is shown in the bottom of the website, and I would like it to count only when it is in viewport. I downloaded the isInViewport jQuery plugin, and tried to merge the two script togethet. But it not works. Could please anybody help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var time = setInterval(function(){TimeNumber();},2);
            var iState = 1;
            var ifSeen = 0;

            function TimeNumber()
            {
              document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = iState;

              if (ifSeen==1) {
                iState++;
              }

              if (iState > 1500) {
                iState = 1500;
              }
            }

            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                "use strict";

                /* activate pause for lightbulb video if scrolled out of viewport */
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                $('time').each(function(){
                    if ($(this).is(":in-viewport( 1000 )")) {
                        ifSeen=1;
                    } else {
                        ifSeen=0;
                    }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Did you mean `$('#time').each { ... }`? (although not sure that makes sense, since your id should be unique anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code to hopefully make it a little clearer.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  "use strict";
  var intervalId = setInterval(function(){TimeNumber();},2);
  var iState = 1;
  var ifSeen = false;
  var $timeElem = $("#time");
  function TimeNumber()
  {
    $timeElem.text(iState);
    if (ifSeen) {
      iState++;
    }

    if (iState > 1500) {
      iState = 1500;
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }

  /* activate pause for lightbulb video if scrolled out of viewport */
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    ifSeen = $timeElem.is(":in-viewport()");
  });
});
```

I put everything inside the `ready`function, so that you can have access to your element. I Created a variable `$timeElem` to hold your element, since you will access it so many times. I turned `ifSeen` into a Boolean, and set it using `.is("in-viewport()")` directly. I could not get the `tolerance` attribute to work (even after adding more than 1000px of content), but this should give you an overall idea. I also clear the interval, so that once the counter hits 1500, it stops.

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/m95833e5/